# how to get more info than generic "Failed to parse JSON: No active field found.; ParsedString returned false; Could not parse value" on BigQuery load?

Tags: google-bigquery

We're trying BigQuery for the first time, with data extracted from mongo in json format. I kept getting this generic parse error upon loading the file. But then I tried a smaller subset of the file, 20 records, and it loaded fine. This tells me it's not the general structure of the file, which I had originally thought was the problem. Is there any way to get more info on the parse error, such as the string of the record that it's trying to parse when it has this error?

I also tried using the max errors field, but that didn't work either.

This was via the website. I also tried it via the Google Cloud SDK command line 'bq load...' and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely caused by some of the JSON records not compying with table schema. It is not clear whether you used `schema autodetect` feature, or you are supplying schema for the load. But here is one example where such error could happen:

```
{ "a" : "1" }
{ "a" : { "b" : "2" } }
```

If you only have a few of these and they are for invalid records - you can automatically ignore them by using `max_bad_records` option for load job. More details at: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json

Comment: I was doing schema autodetect. Also tried using max bad records. Have eventually been able to make progress by loading in smaller batches. Then, when the # of bad records is < the max-bad-records, it sometimes gives errors with better info, like a null element in an array.

Comment: It probably makes sense to first send JSON through some kind of data cleaning/transformation pipeline to make sure you don't lose data and get reasonable behavior from non-conforming records.

Comment: Do you know the general schema of your json file (or at least the schema of the fields you are interested in) ? Using this option will allow you to check the "ignore null values" box.

Comment: To add on the comment by @Mosha Pasumansky , you can find a tutorial on how to implement a dataflow pipeline performing some example data cleansing tasks [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/data-science-preprocessing). You can also use [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/) for this, although it's still in beta.